# move all values from column in one table to new table and update third table with relation between those tables, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, transformation

I am using SQL after a long time and I have following:
I have existing `table1` with columns `id`, `name` and a lot of other columns, it already contains rows.
I created empty `table2` which only has columns `id` and `name`.
I created empty `table3` which only has reference columns `table1_id` and `table2_id`.

Now I want to:

1. take all the values from column `name` in `table1` (can be NULL, discard them in that case),
2. insert them as new rows into `table2`,
3. insert `id`s of the corresponding `table1` and `table2` rows into `table3`,
4. remove the column `name` from `table1`.
   => probably `ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN name;`, but I guess there may be a neater way to cut the result from step 1, transform it and paste as rows in step 2.

EDIT: I came up with something like (not tested yet):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name INTO results FROM table1;
FOR result1 IN
        results
    LOOP
        WITH result2 AS (
            INSERT INTO table2 (name) VALUES (result1.name) RETURNING id
        )
        INSERT INTO table3 (table2_id, table1_id) VALUES (result2.id, result1.id);
    END LOOP;
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN name;
```

EDIT:
I forgot to tell that if the `name` already existed in `table2`, I don't want to add it again (should be unique in table2), but I add the relation between the `id` from `table1` and from the inserted/existing `id` from `table2` into the `table3`.

EDIT:
I found we have source scripts for creating the database and I changed it there. Now I don't know how to get rid of this open question :(

Answer (score 0):

For steps 1) & 2):

```
--Since you already have a table2
DROP TABLE table2;
--Create new table2 with data. Unless you are going to replace NULL with something 
--discarding them would just end up with NULL again.
CREATE table2 AS SELECT id, name from table1;
```

Step 3). Not sure of the purpose of table3 as you would have matching `id` values between table1 and table2. In fact you could use that to set up a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship between them.

Step 4) Your solution: `ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN name;`

Comment: First, thank you. 
I probably explained it incorrectly. I want to select only `id` and `name` columns from table1 and put only the `name` column results as new rows into that table2 so they get their id after the insertion and then I want to add the selected `id`s from table1 and the new `id`s from table2 as a relationship to table3.

Comment: Why create a new relationship when you have an existing one?

Comment: I don't have! I have only `id` from `table1` and I get the different `id` from insertion into `table2`. I forgot to tell that if the `name` already existed in `table2`, I don't add it again (should be unique), but I add the relation between the `id` from `table1` and from the inserted/existing `id` from `table2` into the `table3`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to use it. If you want to run it as one-time transformation in one bulk, this could help (you can try the code on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a02660/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
     id int,
     name varchar(9)
     );
INSERT INTO table1 (
     id,
     name
     )
     VALUES
        (1, 'A'),
        (2, null),
        (3, 'C'),
        (4, null),
        (5, 'E'),
        (6, 'C')
    ;
CREATE TABLE table2 (
     id SERIAL,
     name varchar(9) UNIQUE
     );
INSERT INTO table2 (name)
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM table1
    WHERE name IS NOT NULL
    ;
/*
-- This would be better option, but I was not able to test the merge/upsert function of PostgreSQL
INSERT INTO table2 (name)
    SELECT name
    FROM table1
    WHERE name IS NOT NULL
    ON CONFLICT table2_name_key DO NOTHING --merge/upsert, supports PostgreSQL 9.5 and newer
    ;
*/
CREATE TABLE table3 (
     id_table1 int,
     id_table2 int
     ) AS
    SELECT
        t1.id id_table1,
        t2.id id_table2
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.name = t2.name
    ;
--ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN name;
```

This could also be useful:

- [stackoverflow_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)
- [postgresqltutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/)
- [stackoverflow_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)
- [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) documentation with PL/pgSQL code - suggestion you wrote in question is going much more this way

Comment: Thanks. I think we are going good direction here, will check it in an hour.